# google cloud debugger snapshot reports "No code found at line...", python on managed cloud run

Tags: python, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-debugger

I have a github repo which triggers cloud run build, deployed via console to cloud run. In the debugger setup, I created a GC source repository mirror.  The setup seems to be good.  Pushed changes appear in the debugger console.  I am using a flask server as is canonical in python for cloud run.  The debugee registers, placed after app creation and before routing to my endpoint.  I can see snapshots.  I love it.  Usually.

There comes a point in my code at which the debugger will let me know `No code found at line 75 in /app/app.py. Try lines 69 or 324.`  It's a little interesting that the file has just 87 lines.

Any theories?

Comment: I can't find where to report a bug for the cloud debugger.  Can anyone point the way?

Comment: You can report a bug on the Public Issue Tracker (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Can you share your `app.py` file?