# Google Cloud Debugger snapshot reports error “No code found at line …”

Tags: python, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-debugger

I'm using Cloud Debugger for a Python app (FastAPI) deployed to Cloud Run for Anthos. File source-context.json is used to specify the commit for Cloud Debugger (it was updated before deploying).

Generally, it works as expected, but for some code points Snapshots reports an error like "No code found at line 84 in /app/../api.py. Try lines 83 or 287.". Even though this file has less than 100 lines.

It was reported before for Cloud Run (managed), but with no solution: [google cloud debugger snapshot reports "No code found at line...", python on managed cloud run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612321/google-cloud-debugger-snapshot-reports-no-code-found-at-line-python-on-man)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your app.py file?

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to file a bug on the Public Issue Tracker (cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). as it was suggested by *@Stefan Neacsu*