# Google Cloud Debugger on Cloud Run Django "No code found at line..."

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-debugger

When trying to debug a Cloud Run Django application (Python 3.9) I get the

```
No code found at line 30 in /app/djangotest/urls.py
```

error. I looked at the docker image and the file seems to be in the right place, with debuggable code at the correct location:

```
    29  class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    30      queryset = User.objects.all()
    31      serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

This seems to be similar to:

Flask:
[google cloud debugger snapshot reports "No code found at line...", python on managed cloud run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612321/google-cloud-debugger-snapshot-reports-no-code-found-at-line-python-on-man)

FastAPI:
[Google Cloud Debugger snapshot reports error “No code found at line …”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68544374/google-cloud-debugger-snapshot-reports-error-no-code-found-at-line)

As it seems that there are no answers and no issue has been opened yet, I opened one here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207626319

Comment: You will need to create a complete project with source code if you want someone to look at your issue. They will need to reproduce your error. I recommend putting everything up on GitHub.

Comment: The project is on github already but private, I will give access to whoever wants to look into it, same as for the google cloud project.

Comment: To solve the issue which you are getting, one needs to have access to the Google cloud project. Instead of providing access individually, I would recommend you to open a standard support case in 1:1 channel. You may also refer to this [page](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/) for raising support with this issue.

Comment: The source code is here: https://github.com/cputoaster/cloud-run-test